# Expandable search bar by clicking icon in Materializecss/Material Design

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, materialize

Working on a layout using Materializecss, and in my header/nav I need to display a search icon that, when clicked, expands the search bar.

Ideally I would like it to just take over the entire header/topnav, but anything that expands the/to a search bar is fine.

The documentation (http://materializecss.com/navbar.html) doesn't elaborate on the search bar, aside from mentioning the base code:

```
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <form>
        <div class="input-field">
          <input id="search" type="search" required>
          <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
          <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

How do go about this? Is there a standard method of doing this within Materializecss/Material Design I'm not aware of?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: look at the updated  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkwk7dfL/14/) for improved version of expanding navbar search :) (without unwanted behaviour in chrome)

okay since he want something else as i thinked first, look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkwk7dfL/5/).
some basic jquery functions are required:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var trig = 1;

  //animate searchbar width increase to  +150%
  $('#navbarsearch').click(function(e) {

   if (trig == 1){
      $('#expandtrigger').animate({
        width: '+=150'
      }, 400);
     trig ++; 
     }
    //handle other nav elements visibility here  
    $('.search-hide').addClass('hide');
  });

  // if user leaves the form the width will go back to original state

  $("#navbarsearch").focusout(function() {
    $('#expandtrigger').animate({
      width: '-=150'
    }, 400);
    trig = trig - 1;
    //handle other nav elements visibility here
        $('.search-hide').removeClass('hide');
  });

});
```

Comment: What I mean is, pretty much exactly like the new search bar up top here on SO works. You click it, and it expands.

Comment: ive added what you want to have :) no problem with jquery :)

Comment: and if you want to hide some elements when the searchbar is expanded (it will look better on smaler screens)  use this improved version: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkwk7dfL/3/)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, thank you, but both version have weird behavior when you click to expand and contract. It appears to be only when the "X" is clicked (part of their framework). Do you know why?

Comment: which browser do you use? if i click in the search it expands, and when i click in the page body (under the navbar) it reduces the width as wantend. but at mine it dont reduces the width when i click the x after expanding it.. hm, will have a closer look at the searchbar function of the framework to solve it.

Comment: Same behavior in both FF and Chrome, although in Chrome the input field itself is also missing the full height, which results in the same strange behavior if you click in the search "field", and don't hit the _actual_ input field. It actually breaks the page and makes it inactive, so a refresh is necessary. I don't think it's your code's fault, but rather conflicts with Materialize.

Comment: updated the fiddle, now it should do. expanding on click inside the search, and reduces the width when click the x or on other place :) [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkwk7dfL/6/) i only changed the IDs  in js and in the html markup :) and jes there was a conflict with the css in the framework :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142332/discussion-between-chwzr-and-trace-decoy).

Comment: Sorry to necro this, but hoping you can help (again): For the life of me, I just can't figure out why the search area is 20px higher than the rest of the nav. First I thought it was a padding or margin somewhere, but I've now reset every single thing, and it's just not working. Do you know, by chance?